# Change Property Attribute Like ReadOnly at Design-Time (PropertyGrid)

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes, properties, propertygrid

I develop a custom control that have some field like below:

ControlKind,  Field1 , Field2

I want to change attribute of one of field per controlKind,
Like: if controlKind == useField1, then Field1 show and Field2 hidde in properyGrid (or readonly or filter)

can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement ICustomTypeDescriptor, or register a TypeDescriptionProvider and return a custom type descriptor from that, or apply TypeConverterAttribute.

In all three cases, you need to implement / override the GetProperties method to return a filtered subset of the actual properties.  (In the TypeConverter approach, you must also override GetPropertiesSupported to return true.)

Comment: for the TypeConverter case (which is by far the simplest, btw), simply inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter and you get much for free.